# How to persist two entitys in one transaction?

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb

first: my english is bad..

i have similar scenario:

```
@Entity
public Arm {

    @Id // sequence bla bla bla
    int id;

    @JoinColum
    private Hand mao;

}

@Entity
public Hand {

    @Id // sequence bla bla bla
    private id;

    @Colum
    private String tamanho;

}

@Stateless
public void HandEJB {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void salvar(Braco braco){
        manager.persist(mao);
        manager.persist(braco);
    }

}

== TABLE_HAND ==

ID
SIZE

== TABLE_ARM ==

ID
SIZE
FK_HAND (NOT NULL)
```

first i persist my hand.. after this.. i persist my arm with hand.. 
but (hibernate / jpa / jboss):

> integrity constraint (SA.FK_ED111_HO_REFERENCE_ED110_HO) violated - parent key not found

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you linking the two entities together. If your goal is to assign the hand to the arm, have you tried:

```
Arm a = new Arm();
Hand h = new Hand();
a.setHand(h);
```

then

```
manager.persist(a);
```

You probably want `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` annotated on the Hand field in Arm.

Comment: the exception persist :(

Comment: Hmm, strange, and you now only execute the single persist statement with the arm?

Comment: exactly.. my real problem: http://www.guj.com.br/17360-problemas-com-persistencia-cascata-no-jpa

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that, but maybe the Sequence generator messes things up, have you tried removing that from your classes and fields and replacing it with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` or `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` instead?